# Как скомпилировать на 64-х битном Qt 32-х битное приложение?

Tags: c++, qt

Как скомпилировать на 64-х битном Qt 32-х битное приложение?

Comment: нужно просто выбрать/добавить правильный kit

Answer (score 0):

Это называется [Кросс-платформенная компиляция](https://habrahabr.ru/post/198142/), гугл вам в помощь.

```
./configure -xplatform win32-x-g++ -prefix /usr/local/qt4win32 CROSS_COMPILE=i686-w64-mingw32- -no-webkit -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-script -no-scripttools -no-multimedia -no-qt3support -fast -nomake demos -nomake examples -nomake tools -device-option -little-endian -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -openssl-linked -no-fontconfig -no-3dnow -no-ssse3 -continue
```